# how to handle 206 code with retrofit in android?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I'm new to retrofit and I want to handle the code 206.

So basically I call my rest api and get a Observable but I don't know how to Handle the result and how to call again the api if needed.

for example :

```
Observable<CompanyListRest> vAllCompanyList = api.findAllCompanys1WithParams(vParamsMap);
```

will call my api (param are the start index and the number of element to get)
but how to code the repeat the action.

I try to add a Subscriber with the onNext but it doesn't work

Sorry if it not clear,
thanks

**UPDATE & SOLUTION:**

I follow the znswer of Azim Salimov

```
Observable<Response<CompanyListRest>> vAllCompanyListResponse = api.findAllCompanys1WithParams();
        vAllCompanyListResponse.subscribe(new  Observer<Response<CompanyListRest>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(@NonNull Response <CompanyListRest> pCompanyListRest) {
                if(pCompanyListRest.code() == 206){
                    vAllCompanyList.addAll(pCompanyListRest.body().getCompany());
                    
                    // change parameters of search
    
                    vAllCompanyListResponse.retry().subscribe(this::onNext);
                } else if( pCompanyListRest.code() == 200){
                    return;
                }

            }
```

and this work fine !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your `CompanyListRest` response inside `Response` like below:

```
Observable<Response<CompanyListRest>>
```

`Response` comes from retrofit2:

```
import retrofit2.Response;
```

So now you can check response code for 206 in `onNext` method:

```
@Override 
public void onNext(Resposne<CompanyListRest> response) {
   int statusCode = response.code();
   if(statusCode == 206){
      //do something...
   }
}
```

To call this function again you just simply call this function again).
I would recommend you to have a repository where you can control all your requests.

Comment: thank you !!! now I can check the status code but I have a probleme if the status is 206 this say that there is otehr element to get so I need to recall the same call to have all the element.

So do you know how I can recall it to get the other element ?

Comment: Maybe, you can use the recursion function for this. Just place this request in function and call this function inside the function itself if the status code equals 206. I am not familiar with rxjava but maybe it has functions for this kind of case (I use kotlin coroutines).

Comment: yeah I did this and it work fine ! thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Cool, no problem

Answer (score -1):

well your question is not very clear but if you want to repeat one action you can use "interface".
for example this is my ApiInterface

```
public interface ApiInterface {

@POST("register.php")
Call<User> regCall(@Query("name") String Name, @Query("username") String UserName, @Query("email") String email, @Query("password") String Password);

@GET("login.php")
Call<User> loginCall(@Query("username") String UserName,@Query("email") String email, @Query("password") String Password);
}
```

this is my ApI class

```
public class API {


private static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.6/uni/";
public static Retrofit myRetrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getAPI() {

    if (myRetrofit == null) {

        myRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

    }

    return myRetrofit;

}
```

and when I want to use that in my activity

```
apiInterface = API.getAPI().create(ApiInterface.class);
```

and

```
Call<User> logCall = MainActivity.apiInterface.loginCall(logUser, logEmail, logPassword);

    logCall.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {

            if (Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getApiResposnse().equals("SUCCESS")) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You login successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                prefManager.setLogin(true);
                prefManager.createLoginSession(logUser,logEmail);
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), firstPage.class);
                startActivity(i);
                Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).finish();
                

            } else if (response.body().getApiResposnse().equals("FAILED")) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "LoginFragment failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Username or Password incorrect. please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {

            String loginError = "Connection Error!";
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), loginError + t, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks you for you answer ! 

the status code 206 mean that i don't have all the entity of the server so
can a request the same call with differents parameters do get the other entity ?